# Junit initialization Error: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: from class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.MainMapLookup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, java-8

I am trying to run a simple Junit test. It is testing a spring service call. I had a bug in my code, which I was able to fix and am re running the Junit. However, the Junit test fails at initialization with the following error. I am not sure if my local setup is corrupted or if it is Maven issue. Any help would be appreciated.

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.MapLookup.newMap(I)Ljava/util/HashMap; from class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.MainMapLookup
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.MainMapLookup.<clinit>(MainMapLookup.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.ReflectionUtil.instantiate(ReflectionUtil.java:185)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.<init>(Interpolator.java:65)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:346)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:359)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:420)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:138)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:147)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:175)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:102)
    at com.vanguard.services.logging.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:42)
    at com.vanguard.services.logging.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:47)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:273)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<clinit>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: this is _not_ running on java-8 though...

Answer (score 0):

Your issue could be related to following reason. Please read the comments section under the following issue:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-1386

Now, solution to above problem is available at following link:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-2326

**In summary, upgrading dependencies to log4j from 2.1 to 2.7 and same for slf4j to 1.7.21 could be the solution.**